# Android create .aar files using different Facebook SDK versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, aar

I would like to build my app client side compatible with both Facebook Android SDK 3.x and 4.x since Facebook Android SDK deprecated "Session" class.

How can I write the build.gradle to create one aar file for v3.x and one for v4.x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **flavors**.

Just define your flavors in the `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ....    

    productFlavors {
        flavorSdk3 {
            ...
        }


        flavorSdk4 {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use **different dependencies for your flavors**:

```
dependencies {
    flavorSdk3Compile "..."
    flavorSdk4Compile "..."
}
```

Comment: What should I put in the flavor? Can I do this 
    flavorSdk3 { 
    dependencies { 
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0' 
    } 
    }

Comment: Inside the `flavor` you can define values specified for each flavor for example the `applicationId`, a `buildConfigField`,  a custom sourceset or a custom keystore signing. The `dependencies` block should be outside the `android` block.